# Persist calculated master-block field which depends on details block, within commit

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have a master-block with a details-block. One of the fields in the master-block holds a calculated value which depends on the details-block, and is persisted to the database.

The details-block has POST-INSERT, POST-UPDATE and POST-DELETE form triggers, in which the value of the master-block field is calculated and set:

```
MASTERBLOCK.FIELD1:=FUNC1; --DB Function that queries the details block's table
```

When a form is committed, the following happens:

1. the master block is saved with the stale value
2. the details-block is saved
3. the form triggers are executed and the value of the master block is calculated and set.
4. the master-block field now contains the updated value, but the master-block's record status is not `CHANGED` and the updated value is not saved.

**How can I force the persistence of the calculated field in the master-block?**

Answer (score 0):

> "One of the fields in the master-block holds a calculated value which depends on the details-block"

Generally the ongoing maintenance of calculated totals exceeds the effort required to calculate them on-demand. But there are exceptions, so let's assume this is the case here.

I think this is your problem: `--DB Function that queries the details block's table`. Your processing is split between the client and the server in an unhelpful manner. A better approach would be to either:

1. maintain the total in the master block by capturing the relevant changes in the detail block as they happen (say in navigation triggers); or
2. calculate the total and *update the master record* in a database procedure, returning the total for display in the form.

It's not possible to give a definitive answer without knowing more about the specifics of your case. The key thing is you need to understand the concept of a Transaction as the Unit Of Work, and make sure that all the necessary changes are readied before the database issues the COMMIT.